# Infimum of recursive sequence $x_1 = 8$ and $x_{n+1} = \frac12 x_n + 2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

The given problem was to find what the given sequence $x_1 = 8$ and $x_{n+1} = \frac12 x_n + 2$ converges to.

First by MCT, I proved that it converges because the sequence is monotonically decreasing (by induction), and that it's bounded below by 4.

The thing now is that I actually want to prove what the sequence converges to, and by MCT I know that's the infimum, but I don't know how to go about actually finding the infimum.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

---

Edit: I now know that you don't necessarily need to find the infimum, but I would still like to know how you would approach finding the infimum.

Comment: The limit will satisfy $L=\frac{1}{2}L+2$, i.e., is a fixed point.  Therefore, the limit is $4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that the sequence converge then $x_{n+1}\to L$ and $x_n\to L$ and backing to the recurrence you get:

$$L=\frac{1}{2}L+2\to 2L=L+4\to L=4$$

Comment: So I guess you don't need to find the infimum, and you can use the idea that a sequence and subsequence must converge to the same value. Even if it's not necessary, just as an exercise, could you show me how to find the infimum?

Comment: @AR7: I think that any way to try to find the infimum is equivalent to find the limit. So you can think about the J.G's idea, or think about the sequence $a_n=x_n-x_{n-1}$. All of then will give you both, the limit and the infimum.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the recurrence relation and find the general formula for $x_n$.

The formula for $x_{n+1}=ax_n+b, x_0=c:$

$x_n=\left(c+\frac{b}{a-1}\right)a^n-\frac{b}{a-1}.$

Note that in the given recurrence relation, $x_0=12.$

So: $$x_n=\left(12+\frac{2}{\frac{1}{2}-1}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n-\frac{2}{\frac{1}{2}-1}=8\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n+4.$$

In conclusion, when $n\to\infty, x_n\to4.$

Answer (score 0):

Define $\varepsilon_n=x_n-4$ (the subtracted constant being the limit expected from others' arguments) so $\varepsilon_{n+1}=\frac{\varepsilon_n}{2}$. Thus $\varepsilon_n\to 0$, as required.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? Is this how to find the infimum? Where is $\varepsilon_n$ coming from?

Comment: @AR7 The idea is that, once you've conjectured the limit from $L=\frac{1}{2}L+2$ (which a limit $L$ will satisfy if it exists), you prove the $x_n$ have limit $L$ because they get arbitrarily close to it. Monotonically decreasing sequences that are bounded below have infimum equal to their limit.